# Alter URL using htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Need a htaccess redirect code which will insert `CAE/index.php/` to the URLs.
The redirect code should check if this snippet is present or not in the URL. Only if it is not present, the code should be inserted.

Eg.
The following URL

```
http://localhost/dataPage
```

should be redirected as follows:

```
http://localhost/EWQ/index.php/dataPage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!EWQ/index\.php/).*)$ EWQ/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: What is the URL you tried and where is this htaccess located?

Comment: http://localhost/dataPage is the URL tried. The htaccess is located in the root folder of the website where the index.php resides.

Comment: And what error you got when you opened `http://localhost/dataPage`? Also are there more rules in this .htaccess ?